# How can I find a URL in a span that in a div?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to find a URL thats in a span, which is in a div.

In this case, its the link with the class "company_url" that I'm after.

```html
<div class="links standard">
    <span class="link">
        <a href="https://twitter.com/abacus" class="twitter_url icon_link fontello-twitter" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/abacuslabs" class="facebook_url icon_link fontello-facebook" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/abacus-labs" class="linkedin_url icon_link fontello-linkedin" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link">
        <a href="http://blog.abacus.com/" class="blog_url icon_link fontello-rss" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link">
        <a href="http://abacus.com" class="company_url" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">abacus.com</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I've tested my xpaths for finding the div in the page and the link in the div. So I'm pretty confident that they are correct (I used http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output).

But when I run the code, nothing gets scraped. What am I doing wrong?

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import datetime
from saas.items import StartupItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
name = "abacus"
allowed_domains = ["angel.co"]
start_urls = [
    "https://angel.co/abacus",
]

def parse(self, response):
    questions = Selector(response).xpath('//div[contains(@class, "links standard")]')

    for question in questions:
        item = StartupItem()
        item['startupurl'] = question.xpath('/span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href').extract()[0]
        item['source'] = 'angel.co'
        item['datetime'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two `//`:

```
'.//span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href'
```

Once you do you will get your url:

```
In [2]: from lxml import html

In [3]: x = html.fromstring(h)

In [4]: d = x.xpath('//div[@class="links standard"]')[0]

In [5]: d
Out[5]: <Element div at 0x7f13c0a00208>

In [6]: d.xpath('/span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href')
Out[6]: []

In [7]: d.xpath('.//span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href')
Out[7]: ['http://abacus.com']
```

That is the correct xpath but you need to add a user agent, if you do a `view(response)` in a scrapy shell you see:

[image]

Adding a user agent:

```
~$ scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36" https://angel.co/abacus
```

And then running the code above:

```
In [7]: d = response.xpath('//div[@class="links standard"]')[0]

In [8]:  d.xpath('/span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href').extract_first()

In [9]:  d.xpath('.//span[@class="link"]/a[@class="company_url"]/@href').extract_first()
Out[9]: u'http://abacus.com'
```

Comment: These xpaths work but Scrapy still doesnt download the data. After doing some googling (and proving that the Scrapy code is good by testing it on another site), I'm coing to the conclusion that Angel.co doesnt allow bots to do scraping. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I will have a look at the site when I get back on my notebook

Comment: @user1287245, see the edit. You need to add a user agent in your settings.py